# RMAN - Archivelog deletion policy ignored

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

After a full backup on an Oracle 12.1 database with retention policy set to 1 and ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY BACKED UP 2 TIMES TO DISK, if a run delete obsolete device type disk, all archivelogs are gone even if those are not backed up twice on disk. Why? I'm missing something?
Backup script commands:

```
backup database plus archivelog;
crosscheck backup;
delete obsolete device type disk;
delete expired backup device type disk;
```

Rman settings, out of that, all are default.

```
RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1;
ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY BACKED UP 2 TIMES TO DISK;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/rcmrf/DELETE.html#GUID-FB4EAC69-4978-42F7-8B09-77C6736188B3), explanation of the OBSOLETE option of the DELETE command:

> Deletes data file backups and copies recorded in the RMAN repository
> that are obsolete, that is, no longer needed (see Example 2-78). RMAN
> also deletes obsolete archived redo log files and log backups.
>
> RMAN determines which backups and copies of data files are no longer
> needed, which in turn determines when logs (and backups of logs) are
> no longer needed. RMAN considers the creation of a data file as a
> backup when deciding which logs to keep.
>
> RMAN first uses the options specified with obsOperandList to determine
> which files are obsolete. If you do not specify options in
> obsOperandList, then RMAN uses the options specified in CONFIGURE
> RETENTION POLICY.
>
> Note: DELETE OBSOLETE considers only the backup retention policy and
> does not use the configured archived log deletion policy to determine
> which logs are obsolete. In contrast, DELETE ARCHIVELOG ALL considers
> only the configured archived log deletion policy.

See that last "Note"?

Comment: BTW, Oracle 12 is getting seriously out of date, out of support. Well past time to upgrade.

Comment: I guess I skipped that part, my bad, so it is logically that archivelogs to be deleted. Now the question is, how can I delete previous backup, without delete archivelogs? I just want to keep archivelogs for more days, but to delete previous backup.

Comment: Why do you want to keep archivelogs if they are no longer needed to enforce your recovery window?

Comment: Because I olso have a tape backup which runs Tuesday, and disk backup runs Saturday, if I need the backup and I found disk backup corrupted I want to be able to restore database from tape and to be up to date.

Comment: What is your recovery window definition (rman show retention policy)?  How often are you running rman backups, and what type?  I think you need to update your opening post to show your backup script(s), and the result of 'rman show all'.  It appears that your _real_ requirements are at odds with your current practice.

Comment: 2 full backups per week, one one tape one on disk. Retention policy is to redundancy 1. Rman script refers only to device type disk, there are also other reasons which I must keep archivelogs longer, like shareplex instances. Scrips for backup are in process to be done, I'm still thinking of the best way of doing backup, but I have olso some limitations. I have space for only 2 full backups on disk,  and I need to keep archivelogs for at least 7 days.

Comment: Why don't you change your retention policy to 'x days' (instead of redundancy), take a weekly full backup, and the other six days an incremental differential?  Also, only having space for 2 full backups ... disk is cheap - a lot cheaper than losing a database because of not being able to retain sufficient backup.

Comment: Unfortunately I can take decisions regarding to buy something, and olso the management team disagree with idea of incremental back (they olso know those technically stuff and risks). Told you, a lot of limitations :)). Other solution that I found is to make a script which will delete previous backup using delete backup tag, and archivelogs using util time. Thank you for your time!